# Wait for animation to finish - Python

Tags: python, animation, pyside6

I am trying to fade out some objects in pyside6, I managed to do it, but after the animation I need to change index of Stacked Widget to go to another page. This simulates transition from page to page.

```
def transition_in(self):
    effect1 = QGraphicsOpacityEffect(self.title)
    effect2 = QGraphicsOpacityEffect(self.reminder_btn)
    #
    self.title.setGraphicsEffect(effect1)
    self.reminder_btn.setGraphicsEffect(effect2)
    #
    self.anim_1 = QPropertyAnimation(effect1, b"opacity")
    self.anim_2 = QPropertyAnimation(effect2, b"opacity")
    #
    self.anim_1.setStartValue(0.7)
    self.anim_1.setEndValue(0)
    self.anim_1.setDuration(200)
    self.anim_2.setStartValue(0.7)
    self.anim_2.setEndValue(0)
    self.anim_2.setDuration(200)
    #
    self.anim_group = QParallelAnimationGroup()
    self.anim_group.addAnimation(self.anim_1)
    self.anim_group.addAnimation(self.anim_2)
    self.anim_group.start()
```

The problem is that when trying without changing index of stacked widget, animation works, but when calling `setCurrentIndex` in stacked widget, it instantly goes to the next page. I tried sleep, but it just freezes the program for some time. calling it in a thread does not work either.

Comment: Pages of QStackedWidget cannot shown together, so you cannot both fade out *and* fade in two pages at the same time, unless you "hack" your way around by changing visibility of the target widget (which could still have issues, though). In any case, you obviously should *not* use `sleep()`, if you want for an animation to end, just connect it to its `finished()` signal.

Comment: can you show me an example with `finished()`

Comment: What I need is for the app to wait for animation to end then it execute the following code whcih is to switch to index 1

Comment: apparently this doesn't happen as it considers animation function is executed and finished even if the animation is yet unfinished. @musicamante

Comment: That shouldn't happen, and if it does then you're doing something wrong somewhere else in your code, so please provide a [mre].